# Where in memory are return values stored in memory?

Tags: low-level

Where in memory are return values stored in memory?

Consider the follwing code:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    int result = a+b;
    return result;
}

void main() {
    int sum = add(2, 3);
}
```

When `add(2, 3)` is called, the 2 function parameters are pushed on the stack, the stack frame pointer is pushed on the stack, and a return address is pushed on the stack. The flow of execution then jumps to `add(...)`, and local variables within that function are also stored on the stack.

When `add(...)` is complete, and executes the `return` instruction... where does the return value get stored? How does `[result]` end up in `[sum]`?

Comment: Removed tag. The question has nothing to do with memory segmentation.

Comment: You would find those either on the stack like the parameters, or inside a register, depending on calling conventions and optimization settings. (Of course, in your particular example, the compiler would eleminate the return value alltogether since all inputs are compile-time constants, so it would boild down to a single move instruction with an immediate).

Comment: @Lundin - Thanks, I felt iffy on that one; it was just the name of the chapter in the book where I was reading about parameters on the stack etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This clearly depends on your hardware architecture and your compiler. On 64-bit x86 using `gcc`, your code compiles to:

```
        .file   "call.c"
        .text
.globl add
        .type   add, @function
add:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
        movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
        movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
        leal    (%rdx,%rax), %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax      ; return value placed in EAX
        leave
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   add, .-add
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $3, %esi
        movl    $2, %edi
        call    add
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)      ; the result of add is stored in sum
        leave
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here, the compiler is using the EAX register to communicate the result of `add` to the caller.

You can read up on x86 calling conventions in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: Isn't this implementation wrong ?You are returning local variable address which is deallocated from stack memory as soon as you return from function.As far as i think, you must allocate memory from heap for such implementation.The OP is returning integer,hence registers can accommodate that much(4 bytes), however,lets say,I want to return a structure of 8KB ?I guess registers approach will fail  terribly because they can only return address of structure variable allocated in stack memory of the function that gets deallocated as soon as i return from function.And in such case, i'm doomed :)

Comment: @SPSandhu: I am sorry, but I didn't get any of that.

Comment: @SPSandhu I believe this should answer your query(from the linked Wikipedia article): `"Some compilers return simple data structures with a length of 2 registers or less in the register pair EAX:EDX, and larger structures and class objects requiring special treatment by the exception handler (e.g., a defined constructor, destructor, or assignment) are returned in memory. To pass "in memory", the caller allocates memory and passes a pointer to it as a hidden first parameter; the callee populates the memory and returns the pointer, popping the hidden pointer when returning."`

Answer (score 5):

There is no general answer to this question, because it depends on the target architecture. There is usually a Binary API Spec for any target architecture that defines that and the compiler creates codes that works according to this spec. Most architectures use a register for passing the return value back, simply because it is the fastest way to do it. That is only possible if the value will fit into a register, of course. If not, they might use a register pair (e.g. lower 32 bit in one register, upper 32 bit in another one), or they will pass it back via the stack. Some architectures never use registers and always pass back via the stack. Since the caller must create a stack frame before calling the function (there are exceptions to this rule, but lets stay with the default case here), the stack frame is still there when the function returns to the caller and the caller knows how to access it, it has to know that, since it must also clean the stack frame on return. On most architectures the caller cleans the stack frame, not the callee, since the caller knows how many arguments it has passed via stack (e.g. for a C function that takes a variable number of arguments), while the callee does not (not at compile time, the callee may only know that at runtime), thus it makes more sense to let the caller clean it. And before doing that, the caller can read back any value of the stack frame it wishes to retrieve.

Answer (score 4):

On x86 the return value is put in the EAX register (that may depend on your actual calling convention though).

You could disassemble the code compiled from your source to check what happens for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The function parameters, local variables and return values may be pushed/popped on the stack, or be stored into internal CPU registers, it is highly system dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in the accumulator. For a return value that does not fit into the accumulator, the accumulator will hold a pointer to it on the stack. This is a common scheme, used on the few platforms I have dealt with at that level, but depends on hardware and I think on the compiler/assembler too.

Comment: The definition of an "accumulator" is highly system-specific. It isn't possible to answer the question in a generic way.

Answer (score 0):

EAX is used to store the return value if the size permits it (here it does); it's the caller's action (main in your case) to assign the EAX content to sum